# How to retrieve UILabel's attributed font?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I've attributed UILabel which I've created in storyboard and assigned custom font and colour to it in storyboard itself.

I want to change only the colour of this label. In order to do so, I guess, I need to retrieve label's font. In following code the font is not returned correctly. How do I get the font which I've set in storyboard?

```
extension UILabel {

     func setColour(colour: UIColor) {
        self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: self.text!,
                                             attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: self.font, 
                                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: colour]
                                                 )
    }

}
```

Comment: Would you please refine your question to make it clear and add your code, it might make it more expressive.

Comment: Please read the documentation for the `font` and `textColor` properties of `UILabel`?

Comment: I've added code. I can't get the font correctly from self.font. Since I've set this font in storyboard I should be able to retrieve it?

Comment: There's no need for this `setColour` method. Simply use the `textColor` property to change the color of the label's text.

Comment: I already tried that, it sets the colour but it resets font to system font. I guess I've to specify both colour and font when I change the colour? This is the reason I asked question to get font.

Comment: "I want to change only the colour of this label". So why not: `let attrText = NSMutableAttributedString.init(attributedString: self.attributedText); attrText.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: colour, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrText.string.utf16.count)); self.attributedText = attrText`?

Comment: @Larme Yes, this is what I was looking for. I tried this but it is still resetting the font to system font and also resetting it's size.

Comment: It shouldn't since it itsn't override the font. So the question is when is that method called? And do you play at the same time with `.text` and `.attributedText` (which you shouldn't)

Comment: I've checked it again, it works now. Tx for the help.